# Get Extensions is not working - how to fix it?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

My TYPO3 Backend isn't loading available extensions.

I can't find a solution to this anywhere on google: Just saw something about setting some *curlUrl* parameter to 1 in the Installtool but that didn't work.

I also read something about that it might have to do with the "`Time since last update: unknown`" but I didn't see the solution, it seemed like this has been fixed already in my TYPO3 Version.
How could I get this working again?

> Update Extension List
>
> parsererror(SyntaxError: Ungültiges Zeichen): Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function getUid() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/typo3_src/typo3_src-6.2.25/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Repository/Helper.php
>   on line 248

[image: Get Extensions Fail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Line 248 in `Helper.php`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_6-2-25/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Repository/Helper.php#L248) shows the following `if ($this->extensionRepository->countByRepository($this->repository->getUid()) <= 0) {`.

Thus, it seems, that the contents of your database table `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository` is incomplete or invalid.

### Fix using Install Tool

To fix this, perform the following steps under **TYPO3 CMS 6.2**:

- clear table `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository`, e.g. with SQL command `TRUNCATE tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository;` in e.g. PhpMyAdmin or any MySQL client
- Open TYPO3`s Install Tool, select *Upgrade Wizard* and then the execute button below *Add the default Extension Manager database tables*
- after that there should be at least one entry in table `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository` pointing to "TYPO3.org Main Repository"

### Fix using SQL directly

If that does not help, you can execute the following SQL comment, to add the repository URL in your favorite SQL client (console or PhpMyAdmin):

```
INSERT INTO tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_repository VALUES ('1', '0', 'TYPO3.org Main Repository', 'Main repository on typo3.org. This repository has some mirrors configured which are available with the mirror url.', 'http://typo3.org/wsdl/tx_ter_wsdl.php', 'http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz', '1346191200', '0');
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked - took like 5min to load the list, but it did it :)
Actually my repository table was already empty, I might have emptied it in the past by mistake - so that must've been the reason for the problem in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

No answer to the explicit question, but maybe I can help someone to safe some time!

I had to clean up the `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension` data to get the extension manager work again.

`Install` > `Clean up` > `Clear Tables` > `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension`